# All vertices UVs collapses to a point in the lower left corner of the UV Editor without unwrap

Tags: uv

I am working on a object for texture, when I notice some parts are missing or don't show in the UV Editor of blender or any software for texture, but when I select the vertices only appears at the lower left hand corner.

I search about this issues happened when two objects joined with separate UV maps, then the object looses their UV map and all the uv verts default on top of each other into the lower left hand corner.

How can I repair the UV map without unwrap and back to the original UV map when all the vertices collapses to a point in the lower left corner in new UV  map/material?

[image]

I check *Object Data*/UV Maps only show a UVmap layers, the other object map of one vertex left conner are missing.

My question is if there is a way back to the original UV map missing at the lower left hand corner without unwrapping. The material recognized the vertices, but UV maps don't show properly in the UV editor because they are overlapping when two objects joined since everything just collapses to a point in the lower left corner.

Comment: enable the UV Sync Selection button in the UV Editor window, select the vertices that are at the bottom left and unwrap again?

Comment: Yes, but I try the way back the original uv map missing at the lower left hand corner without unwrapping. The material recognized the vertices, but uv map dont showing properly in the uv editor because is overlapping when two objects joined.

Comment: Select the material but only show in the uv editor at the lower left hand corner.